# Mean estimates of the N price paths not changing over N-iterations

Tags: c++, eigen

I am relatively new to C++, so I apologize if the title is not sufficient. What I am trying to do is get 40 estimates for an option price using N price paths. Essentially I want to get 40 different mean estimates of the N price paths. But I must be doing something wrong because I am getting the same mean price each time. Here is my code:

```
// Generate 40 estimates for the option price, using N paths
    int m = 40;
    MatrixXd SS(N,n+1);
    VectorXd S(m);
    for(int k = 0; k < m; k++){
        MatrixXd Z = generateGaussianNoise(N,n);
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            SS(i,0) = S0;
            for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
                SS(i,j) = SS(i,j-1)*exp((double) (r - pow(sigma,2.0))*dt + sigma*sqrt(dt)*(double)Z(i,j-1));
            }
        }
        S(k) = SS.mean();
    }
cout << S << endl;
}
```

Here is my whole code as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

void crudeMonteCarlo(int N,double K, double r, double S0, double sigma, double T, int n);
VectorXd time_vector(double min, double max, int n);

int main(){
    int N = 100;
    double K = 100;
    double r = 0.2;
    double S0 = 100;
    double sigma = 0.4;
    double T = 0.1;
    int n = 10;

    crudeMonteCarlo(N,K,r,S0,sigma,T,n);

    return 0;
}

VectorXd time_vector(double min, double max, int n){
    VectorXd m(n + 1);
     double delta = (max-min)/n;
     for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
             m(i) = min + i*delta;
     }
    return m;
}

MatrixXd generateGaussianNoise(int M, int N){
    MatrixXd Z(M,N);
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 e2(rd());
    normal_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            Z(i,j) = dist(e2);
        }
    }
    return Z;
}

/*VectorXd Stock_process_Lognormal(double T, double S0, double K, double r, double sigma, int N, int n , int m){
    VectorXd S(m);

}*/

void crudeMonteCarlo(int N,double K, double r, double S0, double sigma, double T, int n){
    // Create time vector
    VectorXd tt = time_vector(0.0,T,n);
    VectorXd t(n);
    double dt = T/n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            t(i) = tt(i+1);
    }

    // Generate standard normal Z matrix
    MatrixXd Z = generateGaussianNoise(N,n);

    // Generate 40 estimates for the option price, using N paths
    int m = 40;
    MatrixXd SS(N,n+1);
    VectorXd S(m);
    for(int k = 0; k < m; k++){
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            SS(i,0) = S0;
            for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
                SS(i,j) = SS(i,j-1)*exp((double) (r - pow(sigma,2.0))*dt + sigma*sqrt(dt)*(double)Z(i,j-1));
            }
        }
        S(k) = SS.mean();
    }
    cout << S << endl;





}
```

I changed my `generateGaussian` function to seed `rd()` although I still the same output (40 estimates of option price). They should be different, since I want to run the for loops 40 times and get the mean of the matrix each time. This is the output for the 40 estimates I get 40 times:

```
99.422
```

Comment: `mt19937 e2(time(0));` as for `srand` do it only once, and share your rand generator.

Comment: Reseeding each loop with `mt19937 e2(time(0));` is not a good idea. [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) has a resolution of 1 second, so  you will produce the same random numbers each iteration if they run within the same second.

Comment: @Jarod42 so are you saying that I should just do that outside of the for loops I have? I just thought I would do it more than once so that I would get a different SS matrix and thus the mean would be different

Comment: You never use your `rd` `random_device` - why not? It would provide a better seed than the `time(0)` you've used.

Comment: assuming your not multi-threading this, try making both `rd` and `e2` static, and initialize `e2`  using `rd`; ie. `static random_device rd; static mt19937 e2(rd());`

Comment: I changed my code around where I seed rd() instead

Comment: Each time I run the program and cout Z I get the same matrix, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the seeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `generateGaussianNoise` before your 40 iteration `k` loop, and nothing within that loop changes the data in the `Z` array that is populated by the randomly generated data.  So every time thru you get the same data.

One way to fix this it to split `generateGaussianNoise` into two functions, one that seeds the random generator (called before the `k` loop) and the other that populates the `Z` array (called from within the `k` loop).

Alternatively, you can generate one seed value outside the loops, then pass that into `generateGaussianNoise` (called from within the `k` loop) while changing the value in every iteration in some way.  Since every iteration would be independent of the previous ones this would then allow a multithreaded simulation if the performance was needed.  You could also use a `seed_seq` to provide multiple seed values to your random number generator (say, the time-based seed value with an iteration based value for the second value in the sequence).

**Edit** with sample implementation:

For example, one implementation of that first way could be to change `generateGaussianNoise` to take the random number engine as a parameter:

```
MatrixXd generateGaussianNoise(int M, int N, mt19937 &e2){
    MatrixXd Z(M,N);
    normal_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            Z(i,j) = dist(e2);
        }
    }
    return Z;
}
```

Then in `crudeMonteCarlo`, where you currently declare `Z`, replace it with

```
mt19937 e2(random_device());
```

This will create and initialize the random number engine for use.  In your `k` loop, before the `i` loop, declare `Z` and call `generateGaussianNoise`, passing in `e2`:

```
MatrixXd Z = generateGaussianNoise(N,n,e2);
```

Comment: Which method would you recommend?

Comment: @Wolfy It depends on what your ultimate goal is.  If you're just doing what you've shown here, the first way is simple to implement and easy to debug.  The second way adds complexity but if your simulation gets more complicated (and takes longer to run) may be worth the extra work (to code and debug) for the reduction in runtime.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail about the first method you proposed I am still a little confused